# symmetrize and mirror not working correctly

Tags: mirror

symmetrize not working correctly

it should copy the left side, x to right side, x+

[image]

[image]

tried the others axis and its not wowrking, tried cursor to selected or origin to geometry and did not works

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/thNZrhTZdJp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know in which way you want to symmetrize this model.

But you should take into account that symmetrize will use the object origin as pivot point and will operate considering the object rotation (at object level).

[image]

(same thing for mirror modifier)

Comment: i want the left side to be on the right side,-x on x but the pivot point is else where, how can i set the pivot point to the middle? why is not seettping to the middle?

Comment: i tried with set center to origin

Comment: tried set origin to geometry tried mirror tried simetrize, did not work nothing on nothing axis tried all axis

Comment: can you illustrate in wish way this is supposed to be mirrored?

Comment: first image, the left side apllied to the right side, the right side does not have the shapes of left side on -y i guess